# exporting environment variables with spaces using jq

Tags: bash, environment-variables, jq

So, I'm trying to export an environment variable that comes from an api that returns json values.  Would like to use jq to just do a one liner, but if the values have spaces I cannot get it working

Trying without surrounding the value in quotes

```
/app/src $ $(echo '{"params":[{ "Name":"KEY","Value":"value with space"}]}' | jq
 -r '.params[] | "export " + .Name + "=" + .Value')
/app/src $ printenv KEY
value
/app/src $
```

Next, I try wrapping the value in quotes

```
/app/src $ $(echo '{"params":[{ "Name":"KEY","Value":"value with space"}]}' | jq
 -r '.params[] | "export " + .Name + "=\"" + .Value + "\""')
sh: export: space": bad variable name
/app/src $
```

Comment: *shudder*. Here there be dragons, and by "dragons" I mean "shell injection vulnerabilities". See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for an explanation of why unquoted expansions don't work to generate shell commands with spaces.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yeah, I understand that, I was just hoping there was a workaround.  I'd never do this with some public api or unknown json, but this is all coming from our internal network private credential store.

Comment: What's the context? Generally it's better practice to load your JSON key/value pairs into an associative array in bash anyhow -- that way you don't need to worry about overriding names that are meaningful to the shell itself (and all-caps keys make that a particular danger).

Comment: BTW, better form is `foo=bar; export foo` rather than `export foo=bar`, such that we're just using a simple assignment rather than calling a separate command (yes, it's builtin, but at the parser level, it's treated as a command). Unfortunately, we *need* the latter form here because the way `jq` escapes names prevents them from being treated as assignments (its output looks like `'foo'='bar'`, and quoting any part of the name side prevents the shell from seeing an assignment).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all of the below, I'm assuming that:

```
json='{"params":[{ "Name":"KEY","Value":"value with space"}]}'
```

---

#### It can be done, but *ONLY IF YOU TRUST YOUR INPUT*.

A solution that uses `eval` might look like:

```
eval "$(jq -r '.params[] | "export \(.Name | @sh)=\(.Value | @sh)"' <<<"$json")"
```

The `@sh` builtin in `jq` escapes content to be `eval`-safe in bash, and the `eval` invocation then ensures that the content goes through all parsing stages (so literal quotes in the data emitted by `jq` become syntactic).

However, all solutions that allow arbitrary shell variables to be assigned have innate security problems, as the ability to set variables like `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LD_PRELOAD` and the like can be leveraged into arbitrary code execution.

---

#### Better form is to generate a NUL-delimited key/value list...

```
build_kv_nsv() {
  jq -j '.params[] |
    ((.Name | gsub("\u0000"; "")),
     "\u0000",
     (.Value | gsub("\u0000"; "")),
     "\u0000")'
}
```

#### ...and either populate an associative array...

```
declare -A content_received=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' name && IFS= read -r -d '' value; do
  content_received[$name]=$value
done < <(build_kv_nsv <<<"$json")

# print the value of the populated associative array
declare -p content_received
```

#### ...or to use a namespace that's prefixed to guarantee safety.

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' name && IFS= read -r -d '' value; do
  printf -v "received_$name" %s "$value" && export "received_$name"
done < <(build_kv_nsv <<<"$json")

# print names and values of our variables that start with received_
declare -p "${!received_@}" >&2
```

Comment: Thanks!   I understand the exploitable issue here and wouldn't use this against some unknown api or json.   Scenario is within a private network where we are retrieving encrypted creds from our credential parameter store

Comment: Trusting content from internal systems is a good way to allow lateral movement from one compromised system to other not-yet-compromised hosts... though granted, if your credential store is popped, you're probably in a bad situation regardless.

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that an attacker who can set arbitrary environment variables can create exported functions, set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to override random C calls if they can get a file of their choice onto your host (even in an otherwise-harmless location like `/tmp`), and otherwise enable a lot of mischief.

Comment: Thanks for all of the updates here.   The credential storage as well as the export forces a prefix on all keys, so I didn't have to worry about conflicts with system envs.     Other security precautions will be added as well.    If I have to I'll build it out into a script, was just trying to work towards a simple one liner.

Comment: @ikegami, the `received_$name` approach creates `received_LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which is safe. The `content_received[LD_LIBRARY_PATH]` approach _also_ doesn't change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

If the values are known not to contain (raw) newlines, and if you have access to `mapfile`, it may be worthwhile considering using it, e.g.

```
$ json='{"params":[{ "Name":"KEY","Value":"value with space"}]}'
$ mapfile -t KEY < <( jq -r '.params[] | .Value' <<< "$json" )
$ echo N=${#KEY[@]}
N=1
```

If the values might contain (raw) newlines, then you'd need a version of `mapfile` with the -d option, which could be used as illustrated below:

```
$ json='{"params":[{ "Name":"KEY1","Value":"value with space"}, { "Name":"KEY2","Value":"value with \n newline"}]}'
$ mapfile -d $'\0' KEY < <( jq -r -j '.params[] | .Value + "\u0000"' <<< "$json" )
$ echo N=${#KEY[@]}
N=2
```