# get value and keys from json to use as export

Tags: bash, jq

I have JSON name values that look like this

```
    {
  "key1": true,
  "key2": "1.9.2",
  "key3": "value3"
   }
```

how can I loop over it using bash  and jq so the output will look like this:

```
export key1=true
export key2="1.9.2"
export key3="value3"
```

Comment: The linked answers unfortunately do not cover the usage of `@sh` which [escapes](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping) the JSON content to be used for shell interpretation, which is an essential security precaution.

Comment: @pmf Feel free to add an answer to the linked duplicate, so that it can be shared as a reference for future

Comment: pmf - or see another post that references usage of `sh` ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51482231/5291015) answer)

Comment: The linked answers help me